# Surge vs upsurge

Tags: word-usage

When to use which?

Definitions by Collins:

[Upsurge](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/upsurge)

> If there is an upsurge in something, there is a sudden, large increase in it

[Surge](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/surge)

> A surge is a sudden large increase in something that has previously been steady

For me these definitions look pretty similar. Something was at some level and then suddenly increased to a much higher level.

Is there some flavor I am missing? Any usage pattern or collocation?

Comment: The crowd surged forward, trampling the low fence and plants. In any case, surge is a verb and upsurge is not.

Comment: @Lambie - But the link provided shows that _surge_ can also be a noun. Compare _rising/uprising, flammable/inflammable_. The prefixes are sometimes used, even though not strictly necessary.

Comment: @KateBunting My point is that upsurge is not a verb. They are both nouns.

Comment: Interesting someone mentioned *inflammable* already. I consider *upsurge* to be one of those words that needed a bit adding because people didn't understand it… just the opposite of *inflammable* which had a bit removed because people [mortally] misunderstood it.

Comment: `But the link provided shows that surge can also be a noun` not the link provided, but the [COCA](https://www.english-corpora.org/coca/) confirms that by usage frequency it is almost always a noun: [surge V](https://i.imgur.com/Nf8PjIC.png) vs [surge N](https://i.imgur.com/5qUvoRM.png). So the statement "surge is a verb and upsurge is not" is simply not true